# Previous visa application on different date of birth

Tags: uk, passports, visa-refusals, applications

I want an advice on this issue.While i was back in Africa(year 2000) i wanted to travel to France to play football and i have to obtain my passport with a lesser age(04/04/1981).My visa was denied because of invalid documentation.No finger print/Biomertic was taken at the French embassy.

Later i have to change back my date of birth to the original one(04/04/1977).Eleven  years later (2013) i got United kingdom work permit on my new passport(original age) and i have been renewing my work permit in the UK on the new passport without any problem.

NOW MY QUESTION:

I am planning to apply for my settlement in the UK and on the form they ask if i have been refused any other country visa.Please, should i mention the France viva i was refused in the year 2000?**Remember i used different date of birth and no finger print taken.**Am just too confused PLEASE ADVISE ME.
Thanks.

Comment: Omo Naija, the answer is yes. They’re not going to check that denial and what date of birth was on it. That was nineteen years ago. No need to lie, especially in this case.

Comment: Even if they check (which I am 99% convinced they won’t) people use passports with wrong names and details sometimes not because of fraud, but because of mistakes by the passport office etc. My second passport had a wrong name but I used it because I had to travel immediately, no time to correct it. In any case in future don’t go and be telling anyone you **deliberately** reduced your age. Just say it was a mistake.

Comment: If you've already omitted the refusals while applying for your UK visas, it might not be the best idea to mention it now. Lying is bad but there's no way for the UK to find out about your French refusal.

Comment: I have rolled back the edit, as it is best to keep the question so that the comments and answer makes sense. The best course of action is for a moderator to migrate it to Expat.SE.